# My Ubuntu 11.10 upgrade failed , And Ubuntu is not working now

Tags: 11.04, upgrade

Please help me in recovering Ubuntu back. A fatal error occurred during 11.10 upgrade. After that my 11.04 has also crashed.

Comment: we need to know more about that, how many HDD you have, how many partitions, do you want to recover or you can erase the entire root partition, the setup of this machine, if you want help you have to write more than that.

Comment: One HDD: 3 windows partition: 2 ubuntu partition: A recovery is better options (tried the recovery option in boot but it is not working) I don't understand what do you mean by setup.Is it the system configuration? then i have 2 gb ram 320 gb hdd and i3 processor.

Comment: yes i mean that, hardware setup to be clear, now the things are a little bit more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to solve this you have to start from the scratch, starting from 0 is always the best options and in this case is the only one that really deserves, but you can do that without losing any data simply copying the content of your partition into another one with the help of Ubuntu that you can run from a USB dongle in live mode.

I can't consider any other option simply because we really don't know what happens to your installation so every other move is really useless and can be too dangerous for your system and your data.

Comment: I agree. Backup all your files first on a separate hard drive, say, an external storage, so you won't lose any data once you start all over again.

Answer (score 0):

My advise is to you that do fresh installation of Precise rather then upgrading it.Back up your all Home folder data before it.